# How to convert small dataset into word embeddings instead of one-hot encoding?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, gensim, word2vec

I have a dataset of 33 words that are a mix of verbs and nouns, for eg. father, sing, etc. I have tried converting them to 1-hot encoding but for my use case, it has been suggested to look into word2vec embedding. I have looked in gensim and glove but struggling to make it work.

**How could I convert my data into an embedding?** Such that two words that may be semantically closer may have a lesser distance between their respective vectors. How may this be achieved or any helpful material on the same?

Such as this[image: embedding]

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion 'they seem to work at a sentence level'? 
Word2vec is specifically a method for creating word embeddings and should work for your case

Comment: Thank you could you share some resource that may help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your dataset is quite small, and I'm assuming it doesn't contain any jargon, it's best to use a pre-trained model in order to save up on training time.

With gensim, it's as simple as:

```
import gensim.downloader as api
wv = api.load('word2vec-google-news-300')
```

The 'word2vec-google-news-300' model has been pre-trained on a part of the Google News Dataset and generalizes well enough to most tasks. Following this, you can create word embeddings/vectors like so:

```
vec = wv['father']
```

And, finally, for computing word similarity:

```
similarity_score = wv.similarity('father', 'sing')
```

Lastly, one major limitation of Word2Vec is it's inability to deal with words that are OOV(out of vocabulary). For such cases, it's best to train a custom model for your corpus.

Comment: Indeed, the best way to get word-vectors well-tuned to the specific word-senses present in a domain-specific corpus is to train your own model – but important to note, word2vec needs *lots* of training data, with many varied examples of every word-of-interest, to generate good vectors.